# React not fetching data from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, web, frontend

I build a react app using nodejs and mysql. I want to update an entry from react but the following code doesn't working and I can't understan what is the problem. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

// from index.js

```
script.get('/updatepost/:id', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `UPDATE posts SET name = '${req.body.name}', school='${req.body.school}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return err;  
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Post updated...');
    })
});
```

//from react component

```
axios(`http://localhost:4000/updatepost/${userId}`, {
method: 'PATCH',
data: qs.stringify(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using patch to send the data (from React), but you are using "get" to receive it (from node).

Try:

```
script.patch('/updatepost/:id', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `UPDATE posts SET name = '${req.body.name}', school='${req.body.school}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return err;  
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Post updated...');
    })
});
```

---

I think you must mistake use the bodyParser middleware. Try installing body-parser on nodejs and adding it before the script patch, as following:

```
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')    

    script.use(bodyParser.json())

    script.patch('/updatepost/:id', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `UPDATE posts SET name = '${req.body.name}', school='${req.body.school}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return err;  
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Post updated...');
    })
});
```

Comment: Do you receive something on req.body, in the node server? Can you console.log the req.body and paste here?

Comment: It says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"